# Plot the occurrence over time of a categorical variable in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, time-series, data-science

I have a dataset of tweets and for each tweet, I have the creation date (*created_at* variable, that has dates in the format *`2021-09-05 12:03:20`* etc ) and the topic of the tweet (*topic* variable; possible values are *Topic 1*, *Topic 2* etc). This is the way in which my dataset is structured:

```
mydata <- read.csv(header=TRUE, text='"tweet","Topic","created_at"
"1","topic1","2018-03-09 13:01:29"
"2","topic2","2018-03-08 10:01:05"
"3","topic3","2018-03-08 12:01:03"
"4","topic4","2018-03-07 22:04:03"
"5","topic5","2018-03-06 15:02:00"
"6","topic6","2018-03-06 14:20:08"
"7","topic1","2018-03-06 12:01:51"')
```

I'm interested in plotting the evolution of the different topics over time (i.e., how many times the different topics occurred in the different days; a time series plot).
Basically, I want the date to be the x of the plot and the y being the n° occurrences of the tweets, with a curve per each topic, so to compare the evolution of the tweets of the different topics over time.

What could I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. (1) This is a little vague, could we have a [mcve] please? (2) Have you searched for similar answers on Stack Overflow yet (I haven't but I bet there are some ...) (3) A general strategy would be (i) compute a "day" variable from `created_at`; (ii) use `aggregate` or tidyverse `group_by()` + `summarise()`; (iii) use the plotting method of your choice (base-R `matplot`, possibly after rearranging output a little bit) or tidyverse `ggplot2`)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this plot is you wanted

```
mydata %>%
  mutate(time = as.Date(created_at), 
         Topic = as.factor(Topic)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, tweet, group = Topic, color = Topic)) +
  geom_point() # + geom_line() + geom_smooth()
```

There are not enougth data points per group, but if your data have enough data,
use `geom_line()` to draw line that pass points(by `Topic`) and `geom_smooth()` to draw smoothed conditional means. See [geom_smooth](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.3.3/topics/geom_smooth) for option arguments.

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

Change `created_at` to `POSIXct` type and extract date from it. Count the number of times a topic was mentioned on each `date`. Plot the chart with a different color for each `Topic`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mydata %>%
  mutate(created_at = lubridate::ymd_hms(created_at), 
         date = as.Date(created_at)) %>%
  count(date, Topic) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, n, color = Topic)) + geom_line()
```